# How to get most recently/latest inserted record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get most recently inserted record in oracle, I have inserted Aditya as last record in email column in table(Table has only one column EMAIL).

Expected output : Aditya

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtCAe.png)

Thank,

Comment: First/Last/Oldest/Newest only have meaning if there is a value in the table you can ORDER BY to enforce the concept - such as an identity value.

Comment: well you can use `ORA_ROWSCN` however if the table is created as rowdependecy

Comment: @Moudiz tried that one(ORA_ROWSCN), but it will take same value for all inserted records in ora_rowscn column. I tried the below query   select ora_rowscn,email,scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) from Table_name order by scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) desc

Comment: @Vijay yes it will not for old records only for the new one.

Comment: @Moudiz yes but if we insert 5 records then it will have same value, we cant make out which one is the latest one or last inserted record